# anybody know the text-domain or unique class of snazzy maps plugin?

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, snazzymaps

https://wordpress.org/plugins/snazzy-maps/

Am using snazzy maps wordpress plug-in to style site maps and i want to add in recommended plug-ins using tgmpa plug-in but for this i need a text domain or unique class to add in recommended plug-ins.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

use `snazzy-maps` as text domain and slug in tgmpa.

**example:**

```
array(
    'name'        => esc_html__( 'Snazzy Map','test'),
    'slug'        => 'snazzy-maps'
),
```

Try that then let me know the result.